# Start new page automatically when using stacked bounding boxes in Prawn

Tags: ruby, prawn

I want to simulate the behaviour of a table in Prawn, but can't use table because of the limitation of things I can draw inside cells.

So I am using bounding boxes in order to create contexts for the elements inside each row. The problem I'm having has to do with the rows.

I'm trying this:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") do
  move_down 50
  bounding_box [0, cursor], width: bounds.width do
    20.times do |i|
      stroke_bounds && start_new_page if (i+1) % 11 == 0
      bounding_box [0, cursor], width: bounds.width, height: 50 do
        fill_color "cccccc"
        fill_rectangle [0, bounds.height], bounds.width, bounds.height
      end
    end
    stroke_bounds
  end
end
```

But I feel this is very hacky and not optimal, due to the fact that the containing bounding_box can't be repositioned after start_new_page (I want it to start a bit higher up), and the fact that I have to manually specify where the page break happens (every 11th element in this case). I tried working with `bounds.parent.height` and with the cursor to check if it reached the end, but it seems the `bounds.height` increases even after the page break.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this solution?

Comment: Maybe if you post the actual formatting issues you have with table, we can address that instead of addressing the workaround, that is buggy.

Comment: have you tried `span`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883834/prawn-float-text-automatically-to-a-new-page