# Prawn: float text automatically to a new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn, prawnto

I have following simple code to generate a pdf.

```
def employe_details
        y = cursor
bounding_box([0, y], :width => 16.cm) do
          @employe.each do |pr|
                txt = pr.week.to_s + ' '
                txt += "work hours"
                text_box txt, size: 11, :at => [0.5.cm, cursor]
                move_down 0.4.cm
            end
              .#more similar texts
              .
              .    
end
```

Problem is, this doesn't create a new page automatically. When the text exceeds first page, rest of the text doesn't show at all or those texts does not show up in a new page.

How to float the texts automatically to a new page when it reaches the end of a page?

**Update:**
Problem with my code seems with this line `:at => [0.5.cm, cursor]`, if I remove the position then it flows to next page, same happens when I use span. If I use position with text in span then it does not flow to next page and if I remove it then it flows to next page. So how can I use something like this

```
text_box txt, size: 11, :at => [0.5.cm]
text txt, size: 11, :at => [0.5.cm]
```

Textbox or text without cursor positions, I need to use x-position because every line has different x-positions.

Comment: I think you can check it, possible, it helps you http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn%2FDocument%3Aspan

Answer (score 2):

`bounding_box` content will not flow onto the next page. You can use [`span`](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/Prawn/Document.html#span-instance_method) instead: (emphasis added)

> A span is a special purpose bounding box that allows a column of elements to be positioned relative to the margin_box.
>
> This method is typically used for **flowing a column of text from one page to the next**.

The [manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) mentions this on page 35:

> This example also shows text flowing across pages following the margin
>   box and other bounding boxes.
>
> ```
> # ...
>
> move_cursor_to 200
> span(350, :position => :center) do
>     text "Span is a different kind of bounding box as it lets the text " +
>          "flow gracefully onto the next page. It doesn't matter if the text " +
>          "started on the middle of the previous page, when it flows to the " +
>          "next page it will start at the beginning." + " _ " * 500 +
>          "I told you it would start on the beginning of this page."
> end
> ```

The result is shown on pages 37/38:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk I can't run your snippet in isolation. Please provide a [mcve] that I can copy and paste.